# How do I get my div to stick on large and medium screens only?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

```
<div class="navigation small-only-text-left large-text-center">
    <a class="button tiny" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="button tiny" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="button tiny" href="#">About us</a>
    <a class="button tiny" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

This is the code I am using in my page. I want some Jquery that will make a div sticky when it hits the top, but only make it sticky on medium screens and up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.resize()` function and test if the window width is greater than *n* pixels (*n* being the smallest width).

In my example below, I used 600 pixels as the smallest medium screen width. For the navigation bar to stick to the top on medium and large windows, it would need fixed positioning and a `top` value of 0. Of course, the function must execute on page load and window resize.

```
function adjustScreen(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth > 600) {
        $('.navigation').css("position", "fixed");
        $('.navigation').css("top", 0);
    } else {
        $('.navigation').css("position", "static");
    }
}

// on load
$(function(){
    adjustScreen();
});

// on resize
$(window).resize(function(){
    adjustScreen();
});
```

It is also easier to use a CSS media query. Just give the navigation bar the aforementioned properties and values, then change its position to `static` in the query.

```
.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navigation {
        position: static;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will really come in handy in the future.